# Android EditText setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an EditText field. When I set onClickListener on it, it will require first the focus on the field and then the click to call the listener. So it's actually two clicks to call the listener. How can I fix this to work from the first click? I don't want to set focusable to false because then the program won't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have said, the first touch focuses the view, the second touch "clicks" it. Instead of implementing `OnClickListener`, implement `OnFocusChangeListener`. e.g.

```
EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myedittext);
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
            //handle your situation here
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Did you debug? Does it reach the focus listener portion at all? If so, is it not reaching the `handle situation` section of code on the first click?

Comment: Now it's working. You have a mistake in your code. onFocus should be onFocusChange. Thanks :)

Comment: Indeed. Not enough coffee this morning. :) Edited that in; Glad it's working for you!

Answer (score 3):

When a EditText is touched in android, first it's focus is changed. OnFocusChangeListener works for the first time.

After that,  onClickListener works every time.

So, if you want to implement something on EditText listener, it is better to implement **setOnTouchListener**

Every time it will work.

Comment: This answer worked for me, I couldn't use setOnFocusListener because it was being called when the Fragment was put on pause, an utterly unexpected behavior and I couldn't find out why. So using onTouchListener worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you mean by there being two clicks in order to call the listener. But if the OnClick method is being called twice and you just want the code to be run once, you could create a flag as a member variable that keeps track of whether the code has already been run. For example, after initializing `firstTime` to `true`, have something like this in your `onClick` method:

```
if (firstTime) {
  // Put code that you want executed once here
  firstTime = false;
}
else {
  firstTime = true;  // Second time: reset the flag
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't the problem. I have to click the field twice before it does anything.

Answer (score 0):

put

```
<requestFocus />
```

in your edittext in xml.
try it, may be helpful for you

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtTxtEmail1"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Email ID" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
```

Comment: Otherwise yes, but I have multiple inputs which all need this action.